# Lua Table Access with Location Given as a String

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a table and I'm trying to access a specific location that is passed in as a String.  What is the easiest way to use the string to access the correct location?

Example, if the table looks like this:

```
a.b1 = true
a.b2.c1 = true
a.b2.c2 = false
a.b3 = true
```

How can I change a.b2.c2 to true given a location 'a.b2.c2' as a string.

Comment: You can use the key as a string accesing the table like `a[str_var]` but this is not taking into account nested tables

Answer (score 0):

If you have just a single level, you can use square-brace indexing:

```
function setSingle(obj, key, value)
    obj[key] = value
end
setSingle(a, "b1", "foo")
print(a.b1) --> foo
```

If you have multiple, you need to do several iterations of this indexing. You can use a loop to do that:

```
function setMultiple(obj, keys, value)
    for i = 1, #keys - 1 do
        obj = obj[keys[i]]
    end

    -- Merely "obj = value" would affect only this local variable
    -- (as above in the loop), rather than modify the table.
    -- So the last index has to be done separately from the loop:
    obj[keys[#keys]] = value
end
setMultiple(a, {"b2", "c1"}, "foo")
print(a.b2.c1) --> foo
```

You can use `string.gmatch` to parse a properly formatted list of keys. `[^.]+` will match "words" made of non-period symbols:

```
function parseDots(str)
    local keys = {}
    for key in str:gmatch "[^.]+" do
        table.insert(keys, key)
    end
    return keys
end
```

Putting this all together,

```
setMultiple(a, parseDots("b2.c2"), "foo")
print(a.b2.c2) --> foo
```

One issue you may run into is that you cannot *create* new tables with this function; you will have to create the containing table before you can create any keys in it. For example, beforing ading `"b4.c3"` you would have to add `"b4"`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `loadstring` to build the statement you want to execute as a string.

```
a = { b2 = {} }

a.b1 = true
a.b2.c1 = true
a.b2.c2 = false
a.b3 = true

str = "a.b2.c2"
loadstring(str .. " = true")()
print(a.b2.c2)
```

Comment: Running a full scripting language to write keys to a table is overkill, and could lead to huge security flaws. It also won't work nicely unless your `a` is a global variable.